# Convert \u emoji string to utf-8 for email body

Tags: php, emoji

I am having the following emoji in a PHP string variable

```
$emoji = "\u{1F9D1}\u{1F4AC}";
echo $emoji;
```

This code above will print the following emoji.

I wanted to embed these emojis inside an Email body. For this, I want to convert them to **&#x1F9D1&#x1F4AC** so that I can place them in the Email body and they will show up correctly.

How do I do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$foo = preg_replace('#\\\u\{(.*?)\}#', '&#x$1;', $emoji);
```

- \u needs to be escaped because it has special meaning in a regular expression, and since the backslash also has special meaning in PHP text literals, we need three of them here.
- { and } also have special meaning, so they need to get escaped with a single backslash.
- (.*?) matches everything (expect newlines), ? makes it ungreedy.
- I added an ; at the end in the replacement - browsers are fault tolerant when it’s missing, but it is technically required by HTML syntax.

---

And the “other direction”, as requested:

```
$emojihtml = '&#x1F9D1;&#x1F4AC;';

$bar = preg_replace('~&#x(.*?);~', '\u{$1}', $emojihtml);
```

(I used `~` for the regex delimiters here, because `#` is part of what we want to match, saves on escaping.)

Comment: Prefect! Can you share how to convert it back the other way around?

Comment: I would not use `$` as the delimiter, because it could cause confusions with `$` used as ending of the string. I´d go with `~` or `/` instead. It does work tho, so its not an error, rather its a confusing thing :)

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt good point, changed it to a `~`. (`$` could also be problematic for some people who prefer to use `"` as their text literal delimiter. Not necessarily here, but situations where PHP takes it as beginning of a variable in a bit more complex expression could also easily occur then.)

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I am wondering why `if ($emoji == $bar)` always returns false for the above.

Comment: $bar contains the _text_ `\u{1F9D1}\u{1F4AC}` after those replacements, but $emoji did contain  to begin with - that’s the difference between _data_ and _code_.

Comment: Why do you need this in both ways to begin with?

Comment: I wanted to place few emojis at the start of an email and once I receive a reply, I could use these emojis as delimiter to strip the quoted body. I can't use strpos or explode unless the delimiter variable contains code and not data.

Comment: Then why not work with the second format exclusively to begin with, why this converting between different notations?